# Disable swipe to scroll on UIWebView but retain dragging/panning

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

On the UIWebView, I'm looking for a way to disable the swipe to scroll (it scrolls when you swipe one finger) but still retaining the ability to drag or panning (hold down a finger while dragging/panning) the webview.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see the difference between swiping and dragging, can you elaborate?

Comment: The difference is with dragging one has to keep pressing in order to get the web view to scroll...

Comment: Seems to be a subtle difference, while a swipe will does exactly the same only for a short time. I guess it's impossible to do such a thing with a UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is a sub class of UIScrollView so you can access all properties of UIScrollView via UIWebView.

So, try this, it will disable scrolling but still user interaction will be on.

```
[web.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Enjoy Coding.......

Comment: This will disable all scrolling.